# Does tagName method works for Firefox?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

After working around some hour finally I came to understand that

`tagName`

method does not work in firefox driver.

The page is similar like this:

```
<table id="xyzList">
   <thead>
       <tr role="row">
           <th >Xyz</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr class="odd" role="row">
           <td class="sorting_1">
               <a href=“/ghj” >Bnm</a>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried working with this, just for test purpose:

`WebElement tR1 = driver.findElement(By.id("xyzList"));
 System.out.println(tR1.findElement(By.tagName("tbody")).getLocation());`

While chromeDriver returns result for this, firefoxDriver shows error that 'Could not locate element with tagname #tbody". But when I put xpath instead of this, it works fine, both in chrome, Firefox:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//*[@id=\"xyzList\"]/tbody")).getLocation());
```

What I want to know is, that am I doing anything wrong or anyone else has came to similar problem?

After searching in internet I do not have enough reference for this except: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/84iaBnYwp6I

Comment: `Could not locate element with tagname #tbody` are you sure you are trying to locate element using tagName("tbody") on table element because error just showing can not find element using provided tag name on the context, need to verify provided context is actually table element or something else. And tagName should be `tbody` instead of `#tbody`. verify it

Comment: And `tB1.findElements(By.id("xyzList"));` will returns list of WebElement instead of single WebElement, it should be `findElement` and could you share what is the `tB1` element here??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Saurabh, I had edited post with findElement for findElemnets and driver for tB1, these are typos. And given context is table element, in chrome it works fine, you can also verify it from the Htmls that I had given.

Comment: What is your firefox version and selenium version??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur OS: mac os X el Capitan, FF Version: 48, Selenium Version: <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-beta3</version>

Comment: I would suggest you please don't use beta version, downgrade selenium to last stable version and use until final version of selenium 3 doesn't released